# I want to convert .csv file to a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I would like to convert a `mydata.csv` file to a Numpy array.

I have a matrix representation `mydata.csv` file
(The matrix is 14*79 with signed values without any header name.)

```
-0.094391   -0.086641   0.31659 0.66066 -0.33076    0.02751 …
-0.26169    -0.022418   0.47564 0.39925 -0.22232    0.16129 …
-0.33073    0.026102    0.62409 -0.098799   -0.086641   0.31832 …
-0.22134    0.15488 0.69289 -0.26515    -0.021011   0.47096 …
```

I thought this code would work for this case.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('mydata.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=False)
```

but it did not work.

and I would like to have final Numpy data shape as `data.shape = (14, 79)`

My error message looks like this though..

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-060012d7c568> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 
----> 3 data = np.genfromtxt('output.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=False)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows, encoding)
   1810                            deletechars=deletechars,
   1811                            case_sensitive=case_sensitive,
-> 1812                            replace_space=replace_space)
   1813     # Make sure the names is a list (for 2.5)
   1814     if names is not None:

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_iotools.py in easy_dtype(ndtype, names, defaultfmt, **validationargs)
    934             # Simple dtype: repeat to match the nb of names
    935             if nbtypes == 0:
--> 936                 formats = tuple([ndtype.type] * len(names))
    937                 names = validate(names, defaultfmt=defaultfmt)
    938                 ndtype = np.dtype(list(zip(names, formats)))

TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Comment: In the sample data the delimiter isn't a comma (probably a tab) and "names" should be "None" or some other things but not "False".

Comment: @MichaelButscher 
`import numpy as np`
`data = np.genfromtxt('mydata.csv', dtype=float, delimiter='\t', names=None)`
but the `data` is now
`[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]`

Comment: Apparently you have tried `delimiter=','` and `delimiter='\t'`.  Can you find out exactly what the delimiter in the file actually is instead of guessing?  How was the file created?  Can you open the file in an editor and check the character(s) that separate the fields?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I will share `mydata.csv` here https://pastebin.com/eKf9Sqip

Comment: Both `np.loadtxt('mydata.csv', delimiter='\t') ` and `np.genfromtxt('mydata.csv', delimiter='\t')` worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you first create a list of `CSV` files (**file_names**) that you want to append. Then you can export this into a single `CSV` file by reshaping Numpy-Array. This will help you to move forward:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

combined_csv_files = pd.concat( [ pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_names ])
```

Now, if you want to **Export** these files into **Single .csv-File**, use like:

```
combined_csv_files.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False)
```

Now, in order to obtain Numpy Array, you can move forward like this:

```
data_set = pd.read_csv('combined_csv.csv', header=None)
data_frames = pd.DataFrame(data_set)

required_array = np.array(data_frames.values)
print(required_array)
```

Here you can also reshape Numpy Array by using:

```
required_array.shape = (100, 14, 79)
```

I have perform simple test on **cmd** to confirm this:

```
>>> y = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
>>> y.shape
(2, 3, 4)
>>> y.shape = (3, 8)
>>> y
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: It worked! but I have another question. If I want to combine a lot of datasets(let say I have mydata_1.csv, mydata_2.csv, mydata_3.csv, mydata_100.csv), how can I combine automatically into a numpy array with shape = (100, 14, 79)?
because I need to use my own data with Convolutional Neural network code, which is used with MNIST dataset.

Comment: @mario119: Instead of adding your requirements in a comment, you should add them to the question. Now the selected answer covers topics not part of the questions, and the actual question has been moved to the background. This is not helpful for those who reach this page with a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mydata = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")
mydata_array = np.array(mydata)

Out:
array([[-0.26169 , -0.022418,  0.47564 ,  0.39925 , -0.22232 ,  0.16129 ],
   [-0.33073 ,  0.026102,  0.62409 , -0.098799, -0.086641,  0.31832 ],
   [-0.22134 ,  0.15488 ,  0.69289 , -0.26515 , -0.021011,  0.47096 ]])
```

Comment: It worked! and I think the output is the numpy array. However, what is difference between `array([.., .., ..], ...])` and `[[... ... ...] [... ... ...]...]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [347]: txt = """-0.094391   -0.086641   0.31659 0.66066 -0.33076    0.02751 
     ...: -0.26169    -0.022418   0.47564 0.39925 -0.22232    0.16129 
     ...: -0.33073    0.026102    0.62409 -0.098799   -0.086641   0.31832 
     ...: -0.22134    0.15488 0.69289 -0.26515    -0.021011   0.47096""".splitli
     ...: nes()                                                                 
In [348]: txt                                                                   
Out[348]: 
['-0.094391   -0.086641   0.31659 0.66066 -0.33076    0.02751',
 '-0.26169    -0.022418   0.47564 0.39925 -0.22232    0.16129',
 '-0.33073    0.026102    0.62409 -0.098799   -0.086641   0.31832',
 '-0.22134    0.15488 0.69289 -0.26515    -0.021011   0.47096']

In [349]: np.genfromtxt(txt)                                                    
Out[349]: 
array([[-0.094391, -0.086641,  0.31659 ,  0.66066 , -0.33076 ,  0.02751 ],
       [-0.26169 , -0.022418,  0.47564 ,  0.39925 , -0.22232 ,  0.16129 ],
       [-0.33073 ,  0.026102,  0.62409 , -0.098799, -0.086641,  0.31832 ],
       [-0.22134 ,  0.15488 ,  0.69289 , -0.26515 , -0.021011,  0.47096 ]])
```

`False` is a bad value for `names`:

```
In [350]: np.genfromtxt(txt, names=False)                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

`names=None` would ok, but that's the default value, so it's not needed.

It looks like the delimiter is whitespace.  I don't see any commas.  The default dtype is float.